# loading a map by lat and lang stored in a database

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I have google map embedded in a page with a Dropdown list containing a number of cities. I have stored the lat and lang values of those cities in a database. A user will select a city and the map will load with respective lat and lang values upon clicking the submit button. Please note that I don't want the geocoding technique. Here is a snippet of my effort.

```js
var map;
var cntr;
var zm;
    
<?php  
    if(!empty($position['lat']) && !empty($position['lang'])){ ?>
      
        var latValue = <?php $position['lat']; ?> ;
        var langValue = <?php $position['lang']; ?> ;  
        
        cntr = {lat: latValue , lng: langValue };
        zm = 8;
                                                              
<?php} else{ ?>
  
        cntr = {lat: 30, lng: 70};
        zm = 7;
            
 <?php } ?>   
   
 function initialize() {
     var mapOptions = {
         center: cntr,
         zoom: zm
      };
   
   //And the rest of the code for markers and infowindows etc.
```

This doesn't work. It even stops the rest of the code to work which perfectly works when I remove this section and assign the default values to the var cntr.
(I am using MVC organization and the $position is an associative arrray of the cities lat and lang in the controller. The query works perfectly.)

Comment: Have you checked the console for the javascript errors ?

Comment: No I have not, but the code is very simple... I don't know if the php tags may be causing any problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have two errors in the code you have provided. First, you have to say

```
<?php echo $position['lat']; ?>
```

not

```
<?php $position['lat']; ?>
```

Second, instead of taking the default values for `lat` and `lng` inside the php loop, initialize the variables at the time you declare them. So the code you need will look something like:

```js
 var map;
   var cntr = {lat: 30, lng: 70};
   var zm = 7;

   <?php if(!empty($position['lat']) && !empty($position['lang'])){ ?>
      
        var latValue = <?php echo $position['lat']; ?> ;
        var langValue = <?php echo $position['lang']; ?> ;  
     
        cntr = {lat: latValue, lng: langValue};
        zm = 8;
                                              
   <?php } ?>
     
   function initialize() {
       var mapOptions = {
            center: cntr,
            zoom: zm
       };
     
     //rest of the code
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use php inside a .js file by default.You have to change your .htaccess accordingly.
Here is a site from a fast google search on how to do it. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/use-php-inside-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

`cntr = {lat: latValue , lang: langValue };`

That should say `lng` not `lang`.

I'm not sure how that would have been reported in the console; it would probably throw an error deep in the API code.

Comment: Note that `lng` is a symbol for **longitude** not **langitude**.

Answer (score 0):

`if(!empty($position['lat'] && !empty($position['lang'])))`

shouldn't this be:

`if(!empty($position['lat']) && !empty($position['lang']))`

?